# Oracle INSTR vs Hive INSTR

Tags: sql, hive, instr

I have Oracle-query and need to use the same in Hive.

```
select INSTR('some string', 's', 1, 1) - INSTR('some string', 's', 1, 2);
>> -5
```

but Hive doesn't have INSTR like Oracle.
I can use only this one:

```
select INSTR('some string', 's');
>> 1
```

and it finds first substring position in string but I need find the second or third and etc.
Oracle query has specific logic thats why I can't change it.

What can I do with it?

Comment: This is working in Hive 4 alpha 2. You may be using older hive version
`select INSTR('some string', 's', 1, 1) - INSTR('some string', 's', 1, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

This was added as part of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-25230 in Hive 4 alpha 2